# Storing serialize array in database?

Tags: php, arrays, database

We are building a crm based application and we are using PDO to access the database. We have various modules like contacts,leads,accounts etc. In the modules we are allowing user to add their multiple information like user can add multiple phone numbers,emails and addresses along with the types like email is of (work,personal).
so to save these kind of multiple informations we are using serialize array in database, for example: for the multiple emails we are storing serialize array in the Email column in database.

Serialize format:

```
a:2:{i:0;a:1:{s:5:"value";s:15:"test1@gmail.com";}i:1;a:1:{s:5:"value";s:15:"test2@gmail.com";}}
```

we want to confirm that way may not create problem later while using filtering etc. so can anyone please suggest us is this a right way to store the multiple information in database?

Comment: We are storing serialized arrays in MySQL too (for example in user permissions) and we haven't got any problems with this.

Comment: Why not just have a table for users, where you save data, that is just one of a kind (like name and so on), have an ID for each person, then have another table, where you save all the data, that may have multiple instances, in another table, that has the user's ID in it? That is the proper way to work with a DB
Example: User Jon Doe. You save name = Jon last_name = Doe in first table. ID is set to auto increment, so he gets ID = 1. Then you set all the other data you insert in table 2, only for ID, you use the ID of the person you are setting the data for.

Comment: Well, you wont't be able to filter/sort/whatever in the database. You'll have to retrieve the data and do everything with own code instead of using existing features which do a much better job. Also a serialized array in a database is like a database in a database, a very bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

I can certainly confirm that this way will create **A LOT OF PROBLEMS** later while using filtering etc.

In general, such an approach is critically against the very **relational database architecture**. It's ok as long as you treat your database as a silly key-value storage, but absolutely unacceptable if you are going to use your database as a database.

The main rule for the database structure should be: each entity have to be stored separately. this way it will be accessible using standard SQL mechanisms.

One of the possible ways to solve your current case, is creating a table with three columns:

```
user_id, param_name, param_value
```